# Show Blur Image Using Glide library

Tags: android, android-glide

i'm trying to show blur image using **Glide** but instead showing error images.i have no idea why it is show error image.**URL** is working fine but still it is showing error image only

**here is my code**

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .load("http://www.gadgetsaint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/cropped-web_hi_res_512.png")
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(context))
                .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                .into(imageView);
```

**BlurTransformation Class:**

```
public class BlurTransformation extends BitmapTransformation {

private RenderScript rs;

public BlurTransformation(Context context) {
    super(context);

    rs = RenderScript.create(context);
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = toTransform.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    // Allocate memory for Renderscript to work with
    Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
            rs,
            blurredBitmap,
            Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL,
            Allocation.USAGE_SHARED
    );
    Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());

    // Load up an instance of the specific script that we want to use.
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setInput(input);

    // Set the blur radius
    script.setRadius(100);

    // Start the ScriptIntrinisicBlur
    script.forEach(output);

    // Copy the output to the blurred bitmap
    output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);

    toTransform.recycle();

    return blurredBitmap;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "blur";
}
}
```

Answer (score 22):

1. Add this library : 
   `implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0`
   For latest version always check change log from here [Glide transformation](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)
2. And where u need to blur image apply this code in your view

```java
    Glide.with(this)
     .load(R.drawable.demo)
     .apply(bitmapTransform(BlurTransformation(25, 3)))
     .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Nice check the changeLog to get the latest version :)

Comment: is this library open source to use?

Comment: Yes it is opensource.

Comment: But this blur effect doesn't affect to the edges.

Answer (score 4):

maybe someone will be useful, the latest version - just Glide:

-add to app gradle:

```
implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
```

-in your layout:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivBlurred"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

-in class, where you add your image:

```
 Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(R.drawable.temp_full_screen_image) // or url
            .transform(BlurTransformation(context))
            .into(ivBlurred)
```

-and finally:

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.renderscript.*
import android.renderscript.RenderScript.RSMessageHandler
import androidx.annotation.ColorInt
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.BitmapPool
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapResource
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.BitmapTransformation
import java.security.MessageDigest

private const val DEFAULT_DOWN_SAMPLING = 0.5f

class BlurTransformation(private val context: Context) : BitmapTransformation() {

    override fun transform(pool: BitmapPool, toTransform: Bitmap, outWidth: Int, outHeight: Int): Bitmap? {
        val source: Bitmap = toTransform
        val scaledWidth = (source.width * DEFAULT_DOWN_SAMPLING).toInt()
        val scaledHeight = (source.height * DEFAULT_DOWN_SAMPLING).toInt()
        val bitmap = pool[scaledWidth, scaledHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888]
        return BitmapResource.obtain(this.blurBitmap(context, source, bitmap, Color.argb(90, 255, 255, 255)), pool)?.get()
    }

    override fun updateDiskCacheKey(messageDigest: MessageDigest) {
        messageDigest.update("blur transformation".toByteArray())
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun blurBitmap(context: Context, source: Bitmap?, bitmap: Bitmap, @ColorInt colorOverlay: Int): Bitmap? {
        if (source == null) return bitmap
        Canvas(bitmap).apply {
            scale(DEFAULT_DOWN_SAMPLING, DEFAULT_DOWN_SAMPLING)
            drawBitmap(source, 0f, 0f, Paint().apply {
                flags = Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG
            })
            drawColor(colorOverlay)
        }
        return try {
            blur(context, bitmap)
        } catch (e: RSRuntimeException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            bitmap
        }
    }

    @Throws(RSRuntimeException::class)
    private fun blur(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        var rs: RenderScript? = null
        var input: Allocation? = null
        var output: Allocation? = null
        var blur: ScriptIntrinsicBlur? = null
        try {
            rs = RenderScript.create(context)
            rs.messageHandler = RSMessageHandler()
            input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT)
            output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.type)
            blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs)).apply {
                setInput(input)
                setRadius(25f)
                forEach(output)
            }
            output.copyTo(bitmap)
        } finally {
            rs?.destroy()
            input?.destroy()
            output?.destroy()
            blur?.destroy()
        }
        return bitmap
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer but deprecated in api31 needs to be updated

Answer (score 3):

If you got a red line under the:

```
 .apply(bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(22)))
```

Just add the RequestOptions

```
.apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(new BlurTransformation(22)))
```

Comment: Why might I prefer this over the existing answers? Please edit your answer to offer an explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This may help you.

```
 Glide.with(context)
    .load(yourUrl)
    .placeholder(yourPlaceholder)
    .override(20,20)
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: This does not blur, this overrides the size of the image and makes it very pixelated, it sort of looks like a blur but its not, its very unprofessional looking if you do this.

Answer (score 2):

For Glide V3 ,

```
 Glide.with(context).load(imagePath).transform(new BlurTransformation(context))
                                        .into(imageView);
```

I am using this Class for Blur Transformation

```
public class BlurTransformation extends BitmapTransformation {

private RenderScript rs;

public BlurTransformation(Context context) {
    super( context );

    rs = RenderScript.create( context );
}

@Override
protected Bitmap transform(BitmapPool pool, Bitmap toTransform, int outWidth, int outHeight) {
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = toTransform.copy( Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true );

    // Allocate memory for Renderscript to work with
    Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(
        rs, 
        blurredBitmap, 
        Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL, 
        Allocation.USAGE_SHARED
    );
    Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());

    // Load up an instance of the specific script that we want to use.
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setInput(input);

    // Set the blur radius
    script.setRadius(10);

    // Start the ScriptIntrinisicBlur
    script.forEach(output);

    // Copy the output to the blurred bitmap
    output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);

    toTransform.recycle();

    return blurredBitmap;
}

@Override
public String getId() {
    return "blur";
}
```

}