# How to blur images with respect to Countdown Timer

Tags: java, android, image, picasso

I have a Blur `ImageView` and a `countdown` timer with 10 sec.
If the timer has `10 seconds` image should be `Max blur` and if the timer value `decreases blur` value also decreases it should show that effect in the image and if the timer value is 0 Image should be Fully clear(without blur).

I have implemented this and it's working fine the `problem` is even after the second image is loaded during the blurring process it blurs the second image with the blurred image of the first image.
I tried to clear the cache with the help of `invalidate`.

```
question_image.invalidate();
Picasso.with(getBaseContext())
   .load(list_question.get(index).getQuestion())
   .into(question_image)
```

Comment: 1) `I have implemented this` there is nothing related to blur . 2) are you blurring it inside adapter ? please explain a bit

Comment: You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084989/show-blur-image-using-glide-library).

Comment: I am blurring an image Inside an BlurImageView